# Remove duplicates from queryset django

Tags: django, web, django-models

I've made this queryset to my django database:

```
 material_purchase=Material_Purchase.objects.order_by("material__id","-purchase__date").values("id","material__id","price","purchase__date")
```

That returned me this:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 8, 'material__id': 1, 'price': Decimal('6.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 31)}, {'id': 2, 'material__id': 1, 'price': Decimal('5.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 4, 29)}, {'id': 9, 'material__id': 1, 'price': Decimal('3.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)}, {'id': 7, 'material__id': 2, 'price': Decimal('10.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 31)}, {'id': 5, 'material__id': 2, 'price': Decimal('20.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 16)}, {'id': 1, 'material__id': 2, 'price': Decimal('27.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 4, 29)}, {'id': 10, 'material__id': 2, 'price': Decimal('5.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)}, {'id': 6, 'material__id': 3, 'price': Decimal('6.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 31)}, {'id': 11, 'material__id': 3, 'price': Decimal('5.00'), 'purchase__date': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)}]>
```

Now I want to delete all the duplicate objects with same 'material__id', except the first( the most recent one). 
I've tried to do this first, with .distinct but my database is sqlite3 and that gives me an error.

Comment: did you tried `material_purchase[0]`?

Comment: yes but if I do del material_purchase[0] it raises method error

Comment: You would have to first make the result a list. `list(material_purchase)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.distinct("material_id")` queryset method will only work on PostgreSQL (see the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)).

If you really must use sqlite for some reason, you could accomplish this with a much less efficient query, first getting the pks of the Materials you want, and then filtering for those pks in your final query.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use distinct, you have to create a [set](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#set) of the *material__id* and get the [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) for every *material__id* in the set and put it into a list.

```
material_purchase = []
qs = Material_Purchase.objects.order_by("material__id","-purchase__date")
for id in set(qs.values_list("material__id", flat=True):
    material_purchase.append(qs.filter(material__id=id).values("id","material__id","price","purchase__date").first())
```

The downside is you will hit the database n+1 times, where n is the number of ids.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the [`.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) queryset method, passing the `material` as argument, something like:

```
Material_Purchase.objects.order_by("material__id","-purchase__date").values("id","material__id","price","purchase__date").distinct('material__id')
```